# Transforming back to date format for plotting after extracting counts in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

I am not sure how to produce a plot as a time series reflecting the number of events per month in [this dataset](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-Present/ijzp-q8t2/explore/query/SELECT%0A%20%20%60id%60%2C%0A%20%20%60case_number%60%2C%0A%20%20%60date%60%2C%0A%20%20%60block%60%2C%0A%20%20%60iucr%60%2C%0A%20%20%60primary_type%60%2C%0A%20%20%60description%60%2C%0A%20%20%60location_description%60%2C%0A%20%20%60arrest%60%2C%0A%20%20%60domestic%60%2C%0A%20%20%60beat%60%2C%0A%20%20%60district%60%2C%0A%20%20%60ward%60%2C%0A%20%20%60community_area%60%2C%0A%20%20%60fbi_code%60%2C%0A%20%20%60x_coordinate%60%2C%0A%20%20%60y_coordinate%60%2C%0A%20%20%60year%60%2C%0A%20%20%60updated_on%60%2C%0A%20%20%60latitude%60%2C%0A%20%20%60longitude%60%2C%0A%20%20%60location%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_awaf_s7ux%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_6mkv_f3dw%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_vrxf_vc4k%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_bdys_3d7i%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_43wa_7qmu%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_rpca_8um6%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_d9mm_jgwp%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_d3ds_rm58%60%2C%0A%20%20%60%3A%40computed_region_8hcu_yrd4%60%0AORDER%20BY%20%60date%60%20DESC%20NULL%20FIRST/page/filter) - the intention if it matters at all was to follow along a youtube presentation on cleaning up datasets that used these data.

Once downloaded as a csv, the steps I followed are:

1. I focused on the "CRIMINAL DAMAGE" category after converting the time column into POSIX, and making the names more easy to handle:

```
chi <- read.csv("chi.csv")
names(chi) <- c("case","date","block","iucr","desc","second","loc",
                "arrest","domes","beat","ward","fbi","x","y","lat",
                "long","location")
chi$date <- as.POSIXct(chi$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
d <- chi %>% filter(chi$desc == "CRIMINAL DAMAGE")
```

At this point, I can use ggplot and get a plot like this:

`ggplot(chi) + aes(x = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month")) +  geom_bar()`

However, I want to get the counts of events per month (for example) and then plot. If there was a column with a variable to sum there would be a bunch of questions on the site to solve the problem. I guess I could also sum rows, or count the number of rows for each week somehow. But this is what I did:

```
d %>% group_by(year=year(date)) %>% count()
d %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% count()
counts <- d %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% count()
library(zoo)
counts$Date <- as.yearmon(paste(counts$year, counts$month), "%Y %m")
c = ts(counts$n, counts$Date)
```

The counts worked just fine, but I got stuck in plotting the results in a way that the x-axis reflects the dates with month and year - not just an ordinal value.

I would like to avoid using ggplot (different reasons).

Answer (score 0):

```
fakedata <- data.frame(
  d= seq.Date(from=as.Date('2020-01-01'),
              to = as.Date('2020-12-31'),
              by= "1 day"),
  v= 1:366
)

plot(fakedata)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

(smry_fk_data <- group_by(fakedata,
         y=year(d),
         m=month(d)) |> count(wt = v) |>
    mutate(datetxt = factor(paste(y,m,sep="-")),
           dnum = as.numeric(datetxt)))

plot(x=smry_fk_data$dnum,
     y=smry_fk_data$n,
     type="b",xaxt="n",
     ylab = "N",
     xlab = "Date")

axis(side=1,
     at = as.numeric(smry_fk_data$datetxt),
     labels = smry_fk_data$datetxt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Two follow-up questions: 1. In the dataset I am working on, I don't have the column you created `v = 1:366` to `count()`. Instead I have to count each entry with the same date belonging to a given month as an event. 2. What is the idea behind  `(wt = v)` in `count()`?

Comment: in my example v stands in for some quantity we want to count for the month. as my data example is by day date, its that days count. These day counts need to be aggregated for a given month, i.e. added together ; I achieve that by using using it as a weight ; without which as i only have 1 row for each v entry, the plot would have been flat/horizontal.

Comment: I see... I don't have a `v` in the dataset - there is no quantity to count - just the number of rows with a date corresponding to any given month... Say, there are 34 entries between Aug 1, 2022 and Aug 31, 2022. Should I count rows? Is the solution `d %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% count()` in the OP not good? Is there a way to then plot this?

Comment: you ask if the OP sol is good, yes its identical to leaving out the wgt stuff if there are no weights and you want the rows counted (weights are implicitly 1. The way to plot is how I showed in my example ... how you set up the count , doesnt change how you would have to plot

Comment: I see... It seems as though you generate a toy dataset with `as.Date()` initially, but later you declass (?) the time values into just `as.numeric()` for the intent of plotting. There has to be a way of using the time values directly as a time series. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: An axis is composed of textual labels to be placed at numeric positions, for flexibility in the text  taking full ownership over both distinct elements seems reasonable to me. If you are content with the default behaviour of plotting with date fields with less customisation that would of course be fine, but I feel it undermines somewhat the thrust of the issue you raised.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I got what I was after. So in case it helps someone else:

```
library(tidyverse)

chi <- read.csv("chi.csv")

dim(chi)
names(chi)
names(chi) <- c("case","date","block","iucr","desc","second","loc",
                "arrest","domes","beat","ward","fbi","x","y","lat",
                "long","location")

chi$date <- as.POSIXct(chi$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

d <- chi %>% filter(chi$desc == "CRIMINAL DAMAGE") 

# ggplot(chi) + aes(x = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month")) + 
  geom_bar()

# Counts per year:
# d %>% group_by(year=year(date)) %>% count()

# Counts per month:
d %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% count()

# Storing the counts in a data frame with years and months:

counts <- d %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% count()

# Converting the two columns of years and months into a single yearmon
# ... and turning the result into a date type with as.Date():

library(zoo)
counts$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(paste(counts$month, counts$year), "%m %Y"))

# Converting the two pertinent columns into a time series:
require(xts)
series <- xts(counts$n, order.by=counts$Date)

# Plotting:
plot(series)
```

[image]